# Creating Hyper-V Images for SharePoint 2010

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, sharepoint-2010

So this [best practise guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx) mentions that I can create a hyper-v image from a new install of SharePoint 2010, is it possible to run more than one machine (copied from this image) on the same network?

I thought you had to have a unique instance of each machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an image, sysprep it, then create differencing disks against it and spawn a bunch of SP images (which will need SP to be configured for each machine). You could also copy the whole image (this has nothing to do with Hyper-V, you can always clone a Sysprepped Windows machine).

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned you want to create whole images of an OS, however I thought you might be interested in a project called AutoSPInstaller.  It allows you to create a pre-compiled/configured working directory.  All you have to do is edit the configuration XML file.

http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/